# autodiscover service couldn't be located

Tags: c#, microsoft-exchange

We are trying to move email from our premises to cloud and facing "autodiscover service couldn't be located" Error.  For some emails same code is working fine but facing issue with with random emails . Is there something missing in cloud migration .

Below is my Code:

_exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
                    _exchangeService.TraceEnabled = true;
                    _exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(_mailbox.EmailAddress, decryptedPassword);

```
             //   _exchangeService.EnableScpLookup = true;
                    _exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(_mailbox.EmailAddress, SslRedirectionCallback);
```

Any Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on why you're using "code" to perform an Exchange migration from on-premise to your cloud presence. I've performed such tasks multiple times and never did I have to modify any "code" so-to-speak. From what source did you update this code?

In regards to "Autodiscover" in general, when performing a migration like this, you generally update your autodiscover DNS records such that mail flow is directed to the cloud presence. From there, the cloud presence makes the decision to insert the messages into "in-cloud" mailboxes or forward them down to a mailbox that still lives "on-prem". This is common as migrations can take a long time to complete, and mail flow can't sustain much disruption.

Any more details you can provide to clear up what you're doing and what you're trying to do will be helpful.